# Prevent rxjs Subject from completing

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

In the example code below `testSubj` is subscribed to twice to `sourceSubj` one of these through the `take` operator. What appears to happen is that when the `take` Observable completes, it causes `testSubj` to complete even though it still has an active subscription.

My question is, why is this the behaviour and is there a way of preventing the Subject from completing?

rxjs 6.4

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const sourceSubj = new Subject<string>();

const testSubj = new Subject<string>();
testSubj.subscribe({
  next: s => console.log(`next: ${s}`), 
  complete: () => console.log(`completed`)
});

sourceSubj.pipe( take(1) ).subscribe(testSubj);
sourceSubj.subscribe(testSubj);
sourceSubj.next('1');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completes because its `complete` method is called when the observable returned by the `take` operator completes.

The subject is an observer and responds to `next`, `error` and `complete` notifications. If you only want to subscribe to `next` and `error` notifications, forward only those to the subject:

```
sourceSubj.pipe(take(1)).subscribe({
  next: value => testSubj.next(value),
  error: error => testSubj.error(error) 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I guess it's just as simple as that from a mechanical standpoint. Follow up though, is there some standard idiom (operator?) for handling this that rxjs provides, or even something in this direction?

Comment: Not really. IMO, connecting separately composed observable streams using a subject in this way is not common. It's not incorrect and I have done it in a number of places - from memory, I passed a subject, as an observer, to `tap`. I would say that it's not sufficiently common to warrant an abstraction.

Comment: ok great! that's exactly what I was looking for, I thought I might be going a bit non standard, thanks for the clarifications :)

Comment: Actually, here's an example in which I pass one to `subscribe`: https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/2aa736127102648936cbf3318d2cb8e0ac1b3ba4/source/observable/traverse.ts#L104-L107

Answer (score 0):

try to think of `Subject` as an object with state, once it completes, it just stopped doing its task

you should just use `merge`
https://codesandbox.io/embed/rxjs-subject-cb86j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import { merge, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const sourceSubj = new Subject<string>();

const first = sourceSubj.pipe(take(1));
const subscription = merge(sourceSubj, first).subscribe({
  next: s => console.log(`next: ${s}`), 
  complete: () => console.log(`completed`)
});

sourceSubj.next('1');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you've missed the point of my question. I know that when the a Subject completes it stops, what's surprising is that the completion of anything that the subject is subscribed to also triggers completion, regardless of any other subscriptions.